# Color output in Sublime Text 2 console?

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor

Is there any way to output coloful text to the sublime text console? I tried this:

```
"\033[0;32mTest\033[0m"
```

and the console displays something similar to this:

```
ESC[0;32mTestESC[0m"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Sublime Text console is essentially monochrome. Its foreground and background colors can be changed via the `Packages/Theme - Default/Widgets.stTheme` file (or your theme's equivalent), but you can't colorize output using terminal escape codes, like you are using.